# Using pseudo-classes add class to parent li

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is there a way of using css pseudo-class to accomplish this: I need to add the class name of the child span (high) to the parent li?

thanks

```
<li class="emergency" style="background-color: #FE9D9D;">
<span class="high">250</span></li>
```

Comment: Not really but I am sure one day we will reach there and then wait another few years for it to become a standard

Comment: NO there is no way to do it with css only you need jQuery!

Comment: `<li class="emergency high">...`

Comment: Couldn't you add the CSS styles from `.high` to `li.emergency`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with CSS.

You can with JQuery however.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li.emergency').each(function () {
        var newClass = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
        $(this).addClass(newClass);
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7mQx/)**

Or you can set the background colour of the span instead. `display: block;` will make the span full width.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="emergency">
        <span class="high">250</span>
    </li>    
    <li class="emergency">
        <span class="low">100</span>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    display: block;    
}
span.high {
    background: red;    
}
span.low {
    background: green;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7mQx/2/)**

Comment: Well you are adding the class but going from the parent to the child while OP asked for the opposite

Comment: I'm looping through the `<li>`s and getting the child `<span>` class then applying it to the `<li>`.

Comment: Thank you, but that won't.  I forgot to mention, the <li> block is generate dynamically in the back end. That's why I would like to use a pseudo-class so it applies to the code once in rendered in the DOM.  *****Yes I'll try the jQueryuery aproach..

Comment: So you just have to wrap my function in `$(document).ready()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: can't you apply the styles that you want to the emergency class instead?

Comment: no because emergency class background only apply when span is high.  sometimes is not high.

Comment: So you could just set the `<span>` to `display: block;` and use CSS only. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7mQx/1/)